# Image size optimizing for newer retina screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I need to implement some photo uploading function, but I'm a little bit confused because of the pixel/size dimension of the images. I need to display a square cropped image which size in IB is 320 x 320.

I've made a little research, but couldn't find an exact answer. I've checked Instagram, and it uses 640 x 640 pixel images everywhere. How is that possible? The iPhone 6 Plus's screen resolution is bigger then the Full Hd, the width of the screen is 1136 px while an Instagram image is 640 px wide (and doesn't pixelated) . I don't think that they save images for every devices separately.

So `UIImageView` can display non-retina images on retina screens like this? Or what's the reason why the 640 px is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView can scale the image you pass to it. So if you were to pass a 640x640 pixel image into a UIImageView that was displayed larger on screen, it would be scaled to fit appropriately. It would scale up and you would lose quality when displayed that way.

As for the IB size being 320x320 points, that doesn't directly translate to pixels. Older devices worked that way, but newer (retina) devices scaled at 2x (including the iPhone 6). So a 320x320 pt UIImageView in IB would actually render at 640x640 pixels. The 6 Plus renders at 3x, so 960x960 pixels.

I'm not sure how you concluded that Instagram was using 640x640 on all devices, but if that is the case, the 6 Plus is scaling images to 960x960 pixels and losing quality. It's possible that the loss isn't noticeable in most cases, but I would guess they request larger images for the larger screen.

http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: I was wrong. I've made an image with instagram on my iphone 6 and sent it to myself in a mail, it's 2448 x 2448 px.